# What is a simple implementation of async.waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I'm using some functions from the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async), and want to make sure I understand how they're doing things internally; however, I'm stuck on  `async.waterfall` ([implementation here](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L529)). The actual implementation uses other functions from within the library, and without much experience, I'm finding it difficult to follow.

Could someone, without worrying about optimization, provide a ***very simple*** implementation that achieves waterfall's functionality? Probably something comparable to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601090/1337422).

From [the docs](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/b3679d50bee2a98c7b399ed7cbb6cc0081c578e5/lib/waterfall.js#L30), waterfall's description:

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their
>   results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an
>   error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and
>   the main callback is immediately called with the error.

An example:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, here is a simple implementation for chaining functions by queuing them.

First of all, the function:

```
function waterfall(arr, cb){} // takes an array and a callback on completion
```

Now, we need to keep track of the array and iterate it:

```
function waterfall(arr, cb){
    var fns = arr.slice(); // make a copy
}
```

Let's start with handling passed and empty array, by adding an extra parameter so we can pass results around called `result`:

```
function waterfall(arr, cb, result){ // result is the initial result
    var fns = arr.slice(); // make a copy
    if(fns.length === 0){
        process.nextTick(function(){ // don't cause race conditions
            cb(null, result); // we're done, nothing more to do
        });
    }
}
```

That's nice:

```
waterfall([], function(err, data){
    console.log("Done!");
});
```

Now, let's handle actually having stuff in:

```
function waterfall(arr, cb, result){ // result is the initial result
    var fns = arr.slice(1); // make a copy, apart from the first element
    if(!arr[0]){ // if there is nothing in the first position
        process.nextTick(function(){ // don't cause race conditions
            cb(null, result); // we're done, nothing more to do
        });
        return;
    }
    var first = arr[0]; // get the first function
    first(function(err, data){ // invoke it
         // when it is done
         if(err) return cb(err); // early error, terminate entire call
         // perform the same call, but without the first function
         // and with its result as the result
         waterfall(fns, cb, data); 
    });
}
```

And that's it! We overcome the fact we can't loop with callbacks by using recursion basically. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvfykcou/) illustrating it.

It's worth mentioning that if we were implementing it with promises we could have used a for loop.

Comment: Here is [a fiddle that allows functions to pass a varying number of arguments along](https://jsfiddle.net/t8uc46c9/8/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who like to keep it short :

```
function waterfall(fn, done){
   fn.length ? fn.shift()(function(err){ err ? done(err) : waterfall(fn, done) }) :  done();
}
```

Comment: will it work with extra args as suggested in question ?